# Apache Tomcat context update listeners

Tags: java, tomcat

I have currently created a LifecycleListener which listens to Tomcat's context deployment event and loads data in a custom configuration file at that point.

I have been trying to find out whether LifecycleListeners support context update and modification events but yet in my understanding I could not discover an appropriate resource to use.

Most specifically, no event type which is triggered at the point of Context modification has been provided. Or does Tomcat first destroy the modified context instance and create a new Context instance which means it calls a destroy event on the Context and then create a new Context instance?

The ones that have come closest to the expectations are as follows:

- A Context WatchedResource which simply observes defined resources
  within a context. But yet in my understanding this does not allow me
  to monitor any modification within the context.
- Java [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

It also has to be noted that currently I am collecting all the deployed Contexts at deployment to a map along with their corresponding custom configuration objects. Hence, there has to be a mechanism through which I am to identify the Context which is modified.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Context modification on tomcat

Comment: Well something like a change to a file within the context, editing the web.xml or some Java class. I believe the Context object will be modified or more precisely a new Context instance is created. What I intend to know is whether they destroy the existing Context instance and create new instance or is there another mechanism?